# Python: Possible to unpack tuple and append to multiple lists in one line?

Tags: python, list

In python, Is it possible to unpack a tuple and append to multiple lists?

Instead of

```
x, y, z = (1, 2, 3)
x_list.append(x)
y_list.append(y)
z_list.append(z)
```

Is it possible to do this in one line?

```
x_list, y_list, z_list ~ (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `x_list[x_list.append(0) or -1], y_list[y_list.append(0) or -1], z_list[z_list.append(0) or -1] = (1, 2, 3)` :-P

Comment: Btw, there *might* be a better way to do what you actually want to do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> x,y,z = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]

>>> x[len(x):],y[len(y):],z[len(z):] = tuple(zip(t))
>>> x
>>> [1,2,3,1]
>>> y
>>> [4,5,6,2]
>>> z
>>> [7,8,9,3]
```

If you wish to insert at start you can do

```
>>> x[:0],y[:0],z[:0] = tuple(zip(t))
```

Comment: The tuple(zip(...)) trick in nice. The +1 are unecessary in the slicing though.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this easily, at least not without overhead.

But what you can do is use a loop to give your code some structure.

```
for lst, j in [(x_list, x), (y_list, y), (z_list, z)]:
    lst.append(j)
```

Another way this can be processed:

```
lst = (x_list, y_list, z_list)
num = (1, 2, 3)

for i, j in zip(lst, num):
    i.append(j)
```

Comment: You can further use `zip((x_list,y_list,z_list),t)` instead of `[(x_list, x), (y_list, y), (z_list, z)]`, where `t` is the original tuple.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a canonical way, but suppose you have lists `l1`, `l2` and `l3`, you can do this.

```
l1[len(l1):], l2[len(l2):], l3[len(l3):] = [1], [2], [3]
```

This is closer to the behaviour of `extend` than `append`.

If that doesn't suit you, you can also one-line it with `zip` and a for-loop.

```
for l, el in zip((l1, l2, l3), (x, y, z)): l.append(el)
```

Comment: I think the first way is closest to what I had in mind, though map is probably what I should have had in mind.. Thank you for this answer. It's similar to @Bro-grammer. Though I think his was first? Thank you!

Comment: His was first but indexing was wrong, but since this has since been corrected I suggest you give him credit.

Answer (score 1):

Given your initial input, you can map a function over the list to cast each element as a list, and then perform the unpacking:

```
x, y, z = map(lambda x:[x], (1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: This overrides existing content of lists.